# Only first popover is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

(There is one similar question I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964140/bootstrap-popover-only-works-on-the-first-item) but I don't think the answer applies to me, or if it does I don't understand how to implement it)

To start, I should say I am not a programmer or designer, I used an open source template made with Bootstrap (called Grayscape) to put up my own site. Meaning: I have no idea what I'm doing. But I try my best and try to read up and learn as I go.

However, I can't figure this out. You'll see on a [test version](http://www.matthewpearl.com/indextest.html#) of my page that there are book covers in the third section (it's a one page layout). I want popovers for each book cover. The first cover's popover works. But only the first one works. Even though the code is the same for the others (I've only put code for the next two book covers, so far).

In the JS script I have this initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function() {
$('.bookovers').popover();
});
```

and then at the bottom before the last body tag I have:

```
$('#popover').popover();
```

Then around the items that have the popovers I have:

```
<a id="popover" class="btn" rel="popover" data-content="Summary text."
              title="title text"
              data-html="true"></a>
```

It wouldn't be hard to confuse me. However, this is one of the last things I need to do to have this page set up and running, and I just can't for the life of me figure out or find why only the first popover works. I experimented and did a popover earlier in the page on some text, and, again, only the first one worked (in other words, the one that had been first, on the first cover, and was now the second one, no longer worked). Any help would be greatly appreciated, but please note I would probably need pretty specific guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: I would try changing the id="popover" and adding a class called popover, then change the code at the bottom of the screen to $('.popover').popover();

id's are meant to be unique, so having more than one element with the same id tends to make weird things happen at times.

Comment: In jQuery, `#` targets an ID, so a single element. `.` targets a class, so multiple elements. Make sure all the elements you want to apply a popover to have the same class (like `.bookovers` for example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a class (e.g. 'myclass') to each element that you want to be a popover, and call popover() on all objects with that class, each object will have its own popover that appears when you click.  That is what I have done with the HTML and JavaScript below.

Also, it looks like you had a duplicate `$(function() {` in your JavaScript.

HTML with multiple popovers (note the "myclass" class):

```
<a class="btn myclass" rel="popover" data-content="Summary text." title="title text" data-html="true">Popover</a>

<a class="btn myclass" rel="popover" data-content="Summary text." title="title text" data-html="true">Popover</a>

<a class="btn myclass" rel="popover" data-content="Summary text." title="title text" data-html="true">Popover</a>
```

JavaScript (note the `$('.myclass')` selector):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bookovers').popover(); // Only necessary if you actually have objects with class "bookovers"
    $('.myclass').popover(); // Makes popover for all elements with class "myclass"
});
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/3ear7ea6/

PS - If you add the class "myclass" (or whichever name you choose) to the elements that already have the class 'bookovers', you can remove the line `$('.bookovers').popover();` from the JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for taking me step by step, Benjamin. It is very kind of you and the others. The popovers work! http://www.matthewpearl.com/indextest4.html … If I could bother you, or any other seeing this, with a follow-up? As you can see at that link, the popovers are staying open unless you click the same book cover again. I'd like them to close when anything else is clicked. I *do* see other threads asking about this with some codes given in answers, but I can't seem to figure out how to adjust the code to fit with my code (which is now adjusted according to your answer above, using "my class")

Comment: Oh! I think I figured out how to have them close. There are probably other solutions, but I found one on the Bootstrap site. Thank you again! http://www.matthewpearl.com/indextest4.html

Comment: I'm happy to help, and I'm glad you figured out how to close them.

Comment: I realized it might be helpful to someone (at least someone clueless as me!) who stumbles onto this, to post how I got them to close. I added this to the attributes of each popover: tabindex="0" role="button" data-trigger="focus"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
<a id="popover" class="btn" rel="popover" data-content="Summary text."
          title="title text"
          data-html="true"></a>
```

Try this:

```
<a class="btn popover" rel="popover" data-content="Summary text."
          title="title text"
          data-html="true"></a>
```

and instead of this:

```
$("#popover").popover();
```

Try This:

`$(".popover").popover();`

The reasoning behind this is because each id is considered to be a unique attribute assigned only to that specific item. By assigning the same id to multiple elements often times there will be mixed results and things may not work properly.

Classes, however, are built on the idea that multiple elements may be grouped together. By adding the class "popover" we can point to those specific elements or select them by using a specific selector. What's a selector? Well When you do this:

```
$("#popover").popover();
```

'#popover' is telling the document to look for an id called "popover". Similarly

```
$(".popover").popover();
```

'.popover' is telling the document to look for a class called "popover"

Comment: This answer would be much more complete if you indicated why the above changes to the code were required.

Comment: @Adam You were correct, so I appended the information!

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this and go over a solution. I think I must have done something wrong when I first tried it -- perhaps because I did not change the code at the bottom of the page? I followed the next answer, which I think is along the same lines, and got it working. I'm so impressed with how generous everyone here is with their time and knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

Can you change the id to each specific popover instead of having the same function for all of them?

Maybe #popover1 #popover2 etc?

Just an idea..

Edit: For example i had a Bootstrap Modal which only pop up the first one until i changed the id to Modal1, Modal2 etc.. This then worked.

Comment: Multiple ID's like that seems a bit redundant when you can just apply a single class to all of them and target it via `.classname`.

Comment: I understand that, could just simply try it individually, i have similar problems in the past and this has worked just to test the functionality.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I ended up doing the class as per Benjamin's instructions above, but it's good to know the options, and learn from them!